# Angular.js app doesn't see a controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a standard app:

```
angular.module('angularFrontApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngResource',
    'ngAnimate'
]).config(AppConfig);
```

and some controller

```
angular.module('angularFrontApp')
    .controller('formsController', formsController);

formsController.$inject = ['$scope', 'AjaxForms', 'appConst'];
function formsController ($scope, AjaxForms, appConst) {

    //.....
}
```

I am trying call a controller in ng-include, but it fails in dynamicTemplate (its dynamic var like some.html):

```
<div ng-include="dynamicTemplate"></div>


<div ng-controller="formsController">some stuff....</div>
```

But if I call the controller outside of include - it works fine.
Why doesn't angular see controllers and other things in includes?

Answer (score 0):

Because your ng-include is wrong: ng-include takes an expression not a string.

```
<div ng-include="'some.html'"></div>
```

Comment: I have no trouble with includes. All content rendered fine.
What if it dynamic include from variable? ng-include="dynamicTemplate".
How can i include that?

Comment: @Oleg_webdev: you can use variables. In my front apps, i store variables in the controller like $scope.url.header , and ng-include="url.header". By doing this, I can add suffix in the url (like `'mytemplate?v=' + build_id`), which allows the application to avoid cache problems when I update the website. If you don't need to take in consideration the cache, you can use strings.

Comment: Still not work.
1) angularjs can include strings without single quotes
2) i include template with variable. Included content rendering but won't find controller

Comment: @Oleg_webdev: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27087730/angularjs-ng-include-and-ng-controller

Comment: What if controller comes from ng-bind-html?
I got data from db put into  <div ng-bind-html="..."> and this data contains <div ng-controller="someController"... How can i get this controller ?